# Why doesn't my audio work everywhere?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, troubleshooting

**System:** HP A642N
**Audio:** Integrated Realtek AC '97
**Operating System:** Windows XP x64
**Network:** Linksys wireless network
**Antivirus:** McAfee Suite

This setup has been running fine for years.

The day before yesterday, I switched from DSL to cable modem, and about the same time discovered that I no longer have sound (I like to listen to internet radio) and my volume icon has disappeared from the taskbar, even though the box is still checked in control panel/sounds and audio devices.

When I go to control panel/sounds and audio devices/sounds/program events and select a sound assigned to an event, I can't preview the sound; that button is grayed out. When I play an online game that uses Java, I still have sound and when I go to control panel/multi channel sound manager, I can conduct the speaker test successfully.

I just have no sound during normal system and program events. I don't think this can be modem change, but I just don't know. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I already downloaded the Realtek audio driver, uninstalled and reinstalled it to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those situations where uninstalling the device in the Device Manager, then rebooting and letting Windows re-detect and re-install drivers for the device, may help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. It made me think of using System Restore. I don't like to use System Restore because of a severe problem it caused for me several years ago, but I went back and l looked at my latest restore points to see what events had occurred around that time, and discovered that maybe a month before I experienced this problem, I had downloaded "360Amigo System Speedup" and installed it. I removed it from my computer and the problem disappeared. Your suggestion reminded me of this resource.